# How do I restrict input in the ion-input?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7, ionic4

I am trying to restrict the user of inputting numbers by removing and not visualizing them.

in html

```
<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="firstName" (ionChange)="check($event)"></ion-input>
```

in .ts

```
 check(event){
     let value : string = event.detail.value;
    event.detail.value = value.replace(/[0-9]/g,'')
}
```

With this code I expected for the user not to see if he inputs numbers. However the value of firstName changes, but the user still sees characters and numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> create one function

```
public onKeyUp(event: any) {

    let newValue = event.target.value;

    let regExp = new RegExp('^[A-Za-z? ]+$');

    if (! regExp.test(newValue)) {
      event.target.value = newValue.slice(0, -1);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean "type=tel" for adding only numbers? I want the opposite, adding only characters

Comment: @IvoNikolov please check my edited code it will help you to solve problems